# What system populates the Flight Stats?

Tags: airline-operations, flight-stat

Which system is in place which gets data from all the flights on a terminal and display them every where like Airport Screens, Websites, different Apps etc?

Comment: The TV screens in a terminal are called [Flight information display system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_information_display_system).

Answer (score 2):

The same system which populates all the data on displays in a Railway Terminal.

For a standalone airport, this data can be mined from ATC of that airport (Which has all the data regarding incoming/outbound flights ).

On an International scale, the data has to be mined from various different agencies. According to a data provider [FlightStats](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByAirport.do#1):

It gets data from:

> Complete, accurate data is the cornerstone of our business and what
> sets us apart from competitive solutions:
>
> Geographic Coverage - FlightStats provides definitive information for approximately 99.5% of U.S. flights, and better than 86% of
> flights worldwide.
>
> Completeness - FlightStats queries multiple sources to create a record for each flight enabling us to offer a broader range of
> information (for example, gate information).
>
> Accuracy - We have invested heavily in the areas of parsing, interpretation and error checking and developed the logic that enables
> handling of difficult issues such as cancellations, diversions and
> changing schedules.
>
> Codeshare Support - Our codeshare logic enables us to deliver flight information for both the operating and the marketing carriers,
> filling what is often a major gap in coverage.
>
> Real-time data sources include:
>
> ```
> FAA ASDI Data Feed
> European Data Feed
> GDS (Sabre, Amadeus, Apollo, Galileo)
> Direct Airport / Airline Data Feeds
> ```
>
> Batch data sources include:
>
> ```
> Innovata Schedules
> TSA Security Wait Times
> Security Information
> Health Information
> Consular Information
> ```

For the system which gets all this data from various different sources, its the central computer database of the airport, which gets data from ATC and the a fore mentioned sources, and this database is accessed by many other end users, including the Screens in the airport